# What happens if I use LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

In my app, I would like to know if the user has setup a passcode or fingerprint (touchID). There's a pretty easy method just for that: `[LAContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication error:error]`.

However, [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lapolicy/lapolicydeviceownerauthentication) say `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` is only available on iOS9 and above. I would rather not crash iOS 8 users without explanation, even if it is getting older. The thing is, I've tried it on an iOS8.4 simulator, and it *seems* to compile and just work.

What ill effects can happen if I use `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` on iOS 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use code similar to this:

```
LAPolicy localAuthPolicy = LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics;
if (![[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"8."]) {
    localAuthPolicy = LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication;
}
```

This ensures I only use `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` on iOS 9 and later.

It's undocumented what actually happens on an iOS 8 device when you attempt to use `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication`. It's very unlikely anything will crash but the authentication may return NO due to an unknown value or it may succeed because iOS 8 only had one valid value and it may not do any checking.

Unfortunately Objective-C doesn't provide any runtime checks for valid enum values like you can do with constants, methods, and classes.

Comment: Makes sense since the enum value has to be defined in a header somewhere and the method call just sees it as an unknown enum value. Just curious, though: when compiling, does xcode not compile against different headers for different versions of iOS?

Comment: No, Xcode compiles only on the Base SDK. And at compile time, enum values are simply replaced by their integer value. So you only pass `1` or `2` as the policy. So the real unknown is what happens under iOS 8 if you were to pass `2` as the policy when only `1` is a known policy in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication` on anything below iOS 9, the app will crash. That is what happened to my app when I didn't realize that this was not available on anything below iOS 9, but my app supported iOS 8.x as its minimum supported OS version.